# Float not returning the right decimal value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is the code i have:

```
int resultInt = [ja.resultCount intValue];
float pages = resultInt / 10;


NSLog(@"%d",resultInt);
NSLog(@"%.2f",pages);
```

the resultInt comes back from php script with the value 3559 so the pages result should be          355.9 but i get the result as 355.00 which isn't right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
float pages = resultInt / 10.0f;
```

`int/int` is `int`
but `int/float` or `float/int` is `float`

---

**Edited** for more explanation

It is important to remember that the resultant value of a mathematical operation is subject to the rules of the receiving variable's data type. The result of a division operation may yield a floating point value. However, if assigned to an integer the fractional part will be lost. Equally important, and less obvious, is the effect of an operation performed on several integers and assigned to a non-integer. In this case, the result is calculated as an integer before being implicitly converted. This means that although the resultant value is assigned to a floating point variable, the fractional part is still truncated unless at least one of the values is explicitly converted first. The following examples illustrate this:

```
int a = 7;
int b = 3;
int integerResult;
float floatResult;

integerResult = a / b;          // integerResult = 2  (truncated)
floatResult = a / b;            // floatResult = 2.0  (truncated)
floatResult = (float)a / b;     // floatResult = 2.33333325
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But it would be nice if you could add some explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I've probably written my comment at the same time as you have updated your answer.

Comment: Why are you using float and not double?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the fact that you're using integer and not float.
Tell the variables that you are using that they are floats and you are done.

```
int resultInt = [ja.resultCount intValue];
float pages = (float)resultInt / 10.f;
```

Comment: The cast isn't needed. Marking the constant as a float is enough. As long as one of the two operands are float, the whole operation will be treated as a float.

Comment: True, but it makes mistake more obvious.